# background-position и зафиксированные 50%, 50%

Tags: jquery, css

Меняю в зависимости от положения мыши свойство background-position блока:

```
...
var cbgpos = x + 'px,' + y + 'px';
$('#cover').css({'background-position': cbgpos});
...
```

(x, y вычисляются отдельно)

В итоге получается такая картина:

```
<div id="cover" style="left: 118px; top: 142px; height: 253px; width: 296px; background-position: 62px 50%, 94px 50%; "></div>
```

Не могу понять, откуда взялись 50% и как от них избавиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var cbgpos = x + 'px ' + y + 'px'; должно без запятой быть